# Swift Compiler Error Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, xcode

```
clubComments.removeAllObjects()
let findClubCommentData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "testObject")

findClubCommentData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil && objects != nil) {
        for object:PFObject! in objects!{
            self.clubComments.addObject(object)
        }

        let array: NSArray = self.clubComments.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
        self.clubComments = array as! NSMutableArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Getting my error from this code... Any suggestions on how to fix it? Im stuck...

Comment: You cannot cast `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @vadian What should I make it?

Comment: Use Swift native types. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift use always native collection types, it avoids those errors. For example the Swift array has a function `reverse()` which is much more efficient than `reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects`

Declare `clubComments` as

```
var  clubComments = [PFObject]()
```

and then try

```
clubComments.removeAll()
let findClubCommentData = PFQuery(className: "testObject")

findClubCommentData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
     if error == nil {
         self.clubComments = objects!.reverse()
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
}
```